# Need get all A tags in selection in editable iframe and add them attribute "class"

Tags: firefox, tags, range, getselection

I have an editable `<iframe>` with the some HTML code in it. I need get all `<a>` tags in my range. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
var select = document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow.getSelection();
var range = select.getRangeAt(0);
//HERE I WANT TO FIND ALL TAGS IN THIS RANGE AND IF IT "A" - ADD NEW ATTRIBUTE "CLASS". SOMETHING LIKE THIS       
var parent = rng.commonAncestorContainer;

for(var i=0; i<parent.childNodes.length; i++)
{
    if(parent.childNodes[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "a")
        parent.childNodes[i].setAttribute("class", "href_class");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to get all `<a>` tags of the range container and then check for each of them whether it actually belongs to the range using [`range.compareBoundaryPoints()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.compareBoundaryPoints) (only parts of the container might be selected). Something like this:

```
var links = rng.commonAncestorContainer.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
  var linkRange = document.createRange();
  linkRange.selectNode(links[i]);
  if (rng.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.START_TO_START, linkRange) <= 0 && rng.compareBoundaryPoints(Range.END_TO_END, linkRange) >= 0)
  {
    links[i].className = "href_class";
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this code works incorrectly. For example i have four strings in editable iframe '<P>First string, first string, first string, </P>
<P><a href="some.html">Second string, second string, second string, second string</a></P>
<P><a href="some.html">More strings, more strings, more strings</a></P>
<P>End string, end string</P>' I selected second and third strings in my iframe in design mode and after selection I want to get all tags (a) from MY SELECTION, not from BODY

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov: Did you actually look at the code? It works correctly for me, see http://jsfiddle.net/ZeNnQ/1/. It only selects elements that are completely contained within the range.

Comment: Wladimir - try to select second and third row (only links). Where is no result in chrome. And your code is only displayed url value, not modified 'a' attribute in iframe selection?

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov: It works correctly for me both in Firefox and in Chrome. Note that it works only for links that are completely within the selection - if you want a different behavior you need to change the `compareBoundaryPoints()` checks. The JSFiddle example displays the URL for demonstration purposes - the code in my answer modifies the class. I seriously suggest that you try to understand the code instead of copying it blindly.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, but i think you dont understand my problem... Your solution is not what I need (( Thanks

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov: И все-таки лучше попытаться понять код, который я вам дал. Stack Overflow не тот сайт, где будут давать полностью готовое решение.

Comment: Владимир, очень рад что мы перешли на наш родной.. Я все внимательно посмотрел, не имею привычки тупо копировать - и готовое решение меня никогда не интересовало.. Я уже месяц в этой запарке, пробую, пытаюсь, экспериментирую.. И самое обидное что нигде в мире подобной задачи ВООБЩЕ не ставилось. Я написал код, который работает, но работает не с выделением а со всем контентом ифрйма.. Скажите - jquery тут не поможет? может с помощью него можно как т воздействовать на user select?

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov: А мой код работает, как ни странно, как раз с выделением. Берет range выделения и просматривает все элементы, которые могли бы в нем содержаться. С помощью `compareBoundaryPoints()` удостоверяется, что элемент полностью входит в range. Если задача найти и те элементы, которые входят в range лишь частично, то условия надо изменить. Но это не меняет того, что код рабочий.

Comment: Смотрите Владимир - я вот выделяю только строки с сылками - в Хроме - у меня ничегошеньки в отладочном окошке не отображает. Выделяю допустим первые три - отображается только первый линк. Выделяю два линка и последнюю строку - ничего не отображается. Но это все не страшно - самое неприячтное что САМЫЙ НУЖНЫЙ вариант - выделение ТОЛЬКО ЛИНКОВ ничего не показывает - а у меня это то как раз и есть главное в затеянной задаче! Подкажите - куда копать, в какую торону? В любом случае - спасибо Вам за помощь!

Comment: Владимир, я модифицировал Ваш без сомнения раборчий код - японял в чем дело, не попадали крайние точки выделения ссылок (при условии если я выделяю только ссылки) спасли rng.setStartBefore(rng.startContainer.parentNode) и rng.setEndAfter(rng.endContainer.parentNode); Теперь все пашет как трактор Беларусь! ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! Едиснвтенная просьба - только Опера ругается на строку linkRange.selectNode(links[i]); Вашего кода. Не знаете что ей не по душе?

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov: Понятия не имею, я с глюками Оперы к счастью уже давно не имею никакого дела.

Comment: Ну я хочу чтобы с моим кодом всем было хорошо, даже юзерам Оперы! но в любом случае спасибо Вам! )

Comment: Владимир здравствуйте! Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли как то положить программно выделение на вставленный в ифрэйм контент - текст, картинку или все вперемешку? именно на то, что пользователь вставил в ифрэйм через ctrl + v или контент. Перехват делать я знаю как, а вот обработать вставленный текст пока не получается ((

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started in the right direction. This code does not do any null reference checks on the iframe, selection, range or list.

```
function addAnchorClass(targetFrameId) {

        var targetIframe = document.getElementById(targetFrameId).contentWindow;
        var selection = targetIframe.getSelection();
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        var alist = range.commonAncestorContainer.getElementsByTagName("a");

        for (var i=0, item; item = alist[i]; i++) {
          if (selection.containsNode(item, true) ) {
            item.className += "PUT YOUR CSS CLASS NAME HERE";
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, he asked about iterating the nodes in a range.